# capture valid comma separated number python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with a multi-line string, trying to capture valid comma separated numbers in the string.

For example:

```
my_string = """42     <---capture 42 in this line
1,234    <---capture 1,234 in this line
3,456,780    <---capture 3,456,780 in this line
34,56,780    <---don't capture anything in this line but 34 and 56,780 captured
1234    <---don't capture anything in this line but 123 and 4 captured
"""
```

Ideally, I want re.findall to return:

```
['42', '1,234', '3,456,780']
```

Here are my code:

```
a = """
42
1,234
3,456,780
34,56,780
1234
"""
regex = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*')
print(regex.findall(a))
```

The result with my code above is:

```
['42', '1,234', '3,456,780', '34', '56,780', '123', '4']
```

But my desired output should be:

```
['42', '1,234', '3,456,780']
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: you don't need the capturing group around the whole regexp.

Comment: Is the result with your code correct? If so, what is your question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, good question. I just fixed my question.

Comment: Given your desired result (`['42', '1,234', '3,456,780']`), what do you mean by, "...but 34 and 56,780 captured" and "...but 123 and 4 captured"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, 34,56,780(has only two digit(56) between commas) and 1234(lacks comma) is not a valid comma separated format. So I want invalid  comma separated number not to be captured.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but those two clauses I mentioned serve no purpose except to confuse the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to capture whole lines that match the pattern, you need to anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`, and use the `re.MULTILINE` flag so that they match line beginnings/endings rather than only string beginning/ending.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$', re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Either I'm missing something obvious or you've forgotten to put the `^` and `$` at the ends of the regex. Without them, the regex has the same result as OP's question.

Comment: @Barmar, Given a multi-line string which only has digits (no white spaces, alphas, etc in each line), your suggestion works. What if each line has alphas and special characters in it as follows?                                                                                            a = """
42 asdfad <-- 42 should be captured in this line
1,234 as  d <-- 1,234 should be captured in this line
3,456,780 <-- 3,456,780 should be captured in this line
34,56,780 <-- nothing should be captured in this line
1234 <--nothing should be captured in this line
"""

Comment: You could put `\D*` after `^` and before `$`.

Comment: @aneroid Oops, I had made the change while testing at regex101 but forgot to copy it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookarounds to make sure we haven't digit or comma before and after the numbers:

```
import re

a = """
42
1,234
3,456,780
34,56,780
1234
"""
regex = re.compile(r'(?<![\d,])\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?![\d,])')
print(regex.findall(a))
```

**Output:**

```
['42', '1,234', '3,456,780']
```